# Why does it say my mainloop is unreachable?

Tags: python, loops, pycharm, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle 
import time

delay = 0.1

ms = turtle.Screen() 
ms.title("hungry snake Game by @Rafa") 
ms.bgcolor("green") 
ms.setup(width=600, height=600)
ms.tracer(0)

head = turtle.Turtle() 
head.speed(0) 
head.shape("square") 
head.color("black") 
head.penup() 
head.goto(0, 0) 
head.direction = "stop"

def move():
    if head.direction == "up":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y + 20)

    if head.direction == "down":
        y = head.ycor()
        head.sety(y - 20)

    if head.direction == "left":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x + 20)

    if head.direction == "right":
        x = head.xcor()
        head.setx(x - 20)


# main game loop

while True:
    ms.update()
    move()

    time.sleep(delay)

//Here is where am having trouble with the code?

ms.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have a never-ending while loop. Anything after that is unreachable

Comment: @khelwood He posted the code with incorrect formatting, I probably got that indentation wrong when fixing it, so I fixed it.

Comment: It should be `turtle.mainloop()`, not `ms.mainloop()`.

Comment: @Barmar The title of the question is asking why code is *unreachable*, not why it doesn't work. Before you reedited it, the last line was unreachable, which is presumably what the question was about.

Comment: Oops, you're right. But he's also calling it wrong, the linked question shows how to fix that.

Comment: @Barmar, `ms.mainloop()` is correct as `mainloop`, in Python 3, is a screen instance method and `ms` contains the screen instance singleton.  `turtle.mainloop()` will also work as it is a function wrapper around an invocation of the method of the same name on the singlar screen instance.  In Python 2.7, which is used in your linked question, the situation is different.

Comment: it works thank you for all your guys help!

Answer (score 0):

The real error here is the use of `while True:` and `sleep()` in an event-driven environment like turtle.  We can replace the infinite loop and the `time.sleep()` with a turtle `ontimer()` method:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

DELAY = 100  # milliseconds

def move():
    if direction == 'up':
        y = turtle.ycor()
        turtle.sety(y + 20)
    elif direction == 'down':
        y = turtle.ycor()
        turtle.sety(y - 20)
    elif direction == 'left':
        x = turtle.xcor()
        turtle.setx(x - 20)
    elif direction == 'right':
        x = turtle.xcor()
        turtle.setx(x + 20)

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(move, DELAY)

def up():
    global direction
    direction = 'up'

def down():
    global direction
    direction = 'down'

def left():
    global direction
    direction = 'left'

def right():
    global direction
    direction = 'right'

screen = Screen()
screen.title("Hungry Snake Game")
screen.bgcolor('green')
screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.tracer(0)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.speed('fastest')
turtle.penup()

direction = 'stop'

screen.onkey(up, 'Up')
screen.onkey(down, 'Down')
screen.onkey(left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(right, 'Right')
screen.listen()

# main game loop

move()

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you share some knowledge on the ontimer. method what is it good for?  @cdlane?